# Correct format for fscanf formatted input using [^...]?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read in a file with the format #string 1##string 2##....etc., using the '#' sign as the only delimiter. I'm also attempting to copy each string into a char array. Here's a bit of my current code, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
char temp[20];
if(fscanf(fp, "%15[^#]", temp ==1) ....
```

fp is opened and declared, and this statement always comes up as false (unsuccessful scan).

Thoughts?

Comment: Does it work with the good ole scanf (or the stdin file)?

Comment: I just noticed that you're passing the result of an equality comparison with 1 as the argument. Is that a typo, or your actual code?

Comment: You need to bypass the `'#'` in the input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably need:

```
if(fscanf(fp, "#%15[^#]#", temp) ==1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [little working example](http://ideone.com/ivMhc). Feel free to change it to suit your needs :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char input[] = "#string 1##string two##three##last but one##five#";
  char tmp[100];
  char *pinput = input;
  /* the conversion specification is
  **                      %99[^#]
  ** the other '#' are literals that must be matched */
  while (sscanf(pinput, "#%99[^#]#", tmp) == 1) {
    printf("got [%s]\n", tmp);
    pinput += strlen(tmp) + 2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```